# utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position

Tags: python, json

I just found out that my json string contains some special characters such as Pandora`®`.
And I get this error `'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position: invalid start byte` when i use this:

```
json.loads(str_to_load)
```

i have tried this to fix the issue:

```
json.loads(unicode(str_to_load), "ISO-8859-1")
```

Apparently, this seems to not working either. How to fix this issue?

The json file is too big to upload here.

Comment: Does this work: `json.loads(str_to_load, encoding="ISO-8859-1")`?

Comment: @SimeonVisser the big question now is, is it returning the correct data?

Comment: P.S. Anybody in this day and age putting anything on the web that's not UTF-8 should be flogged.

Comment: @MarkRansom: and along with that: was the encoding really ISO-8859-1 or did it just happen to return the correct data for this case? So to Co Koder: always check what the encoding is that you're receiving because guessing is difficult.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the encoding in [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
json.loads(str_to_load, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

Answer (score 1):

By default ensure_ascii flag in method json.dumps() is set to True.
To fix this issue, set this flag to False:

```
json.dumps(unicode(str_to_load), ensure_ascii = False)
```