# how to read in csv file with Chinese characters in python

Tags: python

The csv file I have messy code which is supposed to be chinese characters. 
I want to read the file into python with the chinese characters not messy as before. How do I do that?
I tried pandas.read_csv with encoding like gb2312 or gb18030, they all report error like UnicodeDecodeError: 'gb2312' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 4: illegal multibyte sequence

My data:
[image: The data]

CODE    NAME    LISTDATE    FOUNDDATE   TIME    DATE    EPTTM   INDUSTRY    LISTCITY
000001.SZ   Âπ≥ÂÆâÈì∂Ë°å    3/4/1991    19871222    8   1/1/2007    0.030477768 Ω»⁄∑˛ŒÒ    …Ó€⁄
000002.SZ   ‰∏áÁßëA 29/1/1991   19840530    8   1/1/2007    0.025771537 ∑øµÿ≤˙  …Ó€⁄
000004.SZ   ÂõΩÂÜúÁßëÊäÄ    14/1/1991   19860505    8   1/1/2007    -0.05297144 “Ω“©…˙ŒÔ    …Ó€⁄
000005.SZ   ‰∏ñÁ∫™ÊòüÊ∫ê    10/12/1990  19870730    8   1/1/2007    -0.024968897    ∑øµÿ≤˙  …Ó€⁄
000006.SZ   Ê∑±ÊåØ‰∏öA  27/4/1992   19850525    8   1/1/2007    0.074647402 ∑øµÿ≤˙  …Ó€⁄
000007.SZ   ÂÖ®Êñ∞Â•Ω,13/4/1992 19830311    NA  8   1/1/2007    NA  ∑øµÿ≤˙  …Ó€⁄
000008.SZ   Á•ûÂ∑ûÈ´òÈìÅ    7/5/1992    19891011    8   1/1/2007    -0.010574387    ◊€∫œ    …Ó€⁄
000009.SZ   ‰∏≠ÂõΩÂÆùÂÆâ    25/6/1991   19830706    8   1/1/2007    0.009576133 ∑øµÿ≤˙  …Ó€⁄

Comment: Are you *sure* the file is ASCII encoded wtih gb2312? Perhaps it's UTF8? How *did* you specify the encoding? [In this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579248/utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xae-in-position) the dev tried to "convert" the file when all that was needed was to specify the correct encoding

Comment: The image you posted doesn't show chinese characters. It's ASCII that was read using the wrong codepage. It's *already* mangled. Post a sample of the source file in the question text, not as an image. Text in images can't be copied, compiled and its byte values can't be inspected

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think it's possible the text *is* Chinese (say, UTF8), but was opened in a different (one-byte?) encoding.

Comment: @Norrius it's definitely a  wrong encoding but I doubt the source was UTF8. If that were the case there would be repeating `U+0080` glyphs every 3 bytes or `U+10000` every 4. UTF8 characters above the ANSI range take 2+ bytes with the first one always `U+0080` for 2-3 byte characters or `U+10000` for 4 byte characters.

Comment: @Norrius We can't be sure though because 0x80 is treated either as a control character or € in various codepages. It's impossible to guess whether there's an invisible control character every 3 bytes from the image. If the OP posted the text it would be easy. In fact, one could try detecting the codepage with a script that converted the mangled text into Unicode and excluded all codepages that resulted in error (�)or unexpected characters like Ω

Comment: Eva, it is possible the original file is correct (or at least "salvageable") but the data gets messed up when copying it into your question. Can you upload the *original* file somewhere and add a link to your question?

Answer (score 1):

`data06_16 = pd.read_csv("yourfile.csv", encoding="GBK")`

Try adding encoding equals to GBK, it work well.

as the screenshot.

[image]